# How to initialize a mpz_t in gmp with a 1024-bit number from a character string?

Tags: c, gmp

I want to initialize a `mpz_t` variable in gmp with a very large value like a 1024 bit large integer. How can I do so ? I am new to gmp. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to initialize it with? A given number? A random number? Zero? In what form is your initial data?

Comment: i want to intialize with a given number

Comment: Well, yes, but how are you given that number -- as a binary, as an ASCII string of numerals, etc.

Comment: a string of numerals would do

Comment: Then it's trivial, use the constructor. I'll post. Edit: Oh, wait, this is C, not C++... editing!

Answer (score 7):

Use [`mpz_import`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html#Integer-Import-and-Export).  For example:

```
uint8_t input[128];
mpz_t z;
mpz_init(z);

// Convert the 1024-bit number 'input' into an mpz_t, with the most significant byte
// first and using native endianness within each byte.
mpz_import(z, sizeof(input), 1, sizeof(input[0]), 0, 0, input);
```

Answer (score 3):

To initialize a GMP integer from a string in C++, you can use `libgmp++` and directly use a constructor:

```
#include <gmpxx.h>

const std::string my_number = "12345678901234567890";

mpz_class n(my_number); // done!
```

If you still need the raw `mpz_t` type, say `n.get_mpz_t()`.

In C, you have to spell it out like this:

```
#include <gmp.h>

const char * const my_number = "12345678901234567890";
int err;

mpz_t n;
mpz_init(n);
err = mpz_set_str(n, my_number);    /* check that err == 0 ! */

/* ... */

mpz_clear(n);
```

See the [documentation](http://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers.html#Initializing-Integers) for further ways to initialize integers.

Comment: `mpz_class n("12345678901234567890");` also works here.