# Converting array of unsigned non printable values to string

Tags: c++, type-conversion, gmp, unsigned-char

I have an array of unsigned characters, produced by hash function. I want to convert it to string or ascii code or hexdecimal. The value at the moment are gibberish and hash are nonsense. I need to know how I can convert them. 
Any help would be much appreciated.  The array a byte array or unsigned char array. I'm using C++. The array is so big and the actual values represents a big integer (as it is output of a hash function).

Note: At the end I want a big integer of type mpz_t (I'm using gmp library).

Comment: First decide to what it should converted. A raw data blob to ... hex, base64, ...?

Comment: @deviantfan Ideally to mpz_t type or big integer type. However, if I get it in any readable form I can convert it to big integer on my own. I'll edit the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6684154/3134621

Comment: read the gmp library documentation to find out the format of `mpz_t` and then make one?

Comment: @deviantfan Thank you very much. That's exactly what I want. Shall I remove my question or leave it as is?

Comment: @user153465 It's no problem to leave it, and it could be useful for other people finding it per Google etc. too. Soon it gets marked as duplicate of the other question, then the link is better visible above your text too.